# golang cgo cc1.exe: fatal error: opening output file 2: Permission denied

Tags: go, cgo

System environment variables

```
$ where go
D:\Program Files\Go\bin\go.exe

$ where gcc
D:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe

$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-10.3.0/configure --prefix=/mingw64 --with-local-prefix=/mingw64/local --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-native-system-header-dir=/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include --libexecdir=/mingw64/lib --enable-bootstrap --enable-checking=release --with-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,lto,c++,fortran,ada,objc,obj-c++,jit --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-graphite --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-multilib --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/mingw64 --with-mpfr=/mingw64 --with-mpc=/mingw64 --with-isl=/mingw64 --with-pkgversion='Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-boot-ldflags='-pipe -Wl,--dynamicbase,--high-entropy-va,--nxcompat,--default-image-base-high -Wl,--disable-dynamicbase -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc' 'LDFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-pipe -Wl,--dynamicbase,--high-entropy-va,--nxcompat,--default-image-base-high' --enable-linker-plugin-flags='LDFLAGS=-static-libstdc++\ -static-libgcc\ -pipe\ -Wl,--dynamicbase,--high-entropy-va,--nxcompat,--default-image-base-high\ -Wl,--stack,12582912'
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 10.3.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)

$ go env
set GO111MODULE=on
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\ChenHN\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\ChenHN\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOEXPERIMENT=
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=git.iot
set GOMODCACHE=D:\go3\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=git.iot
set GONOSUMDB=git.iot
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=D:\go3
set GOPRIVATE=git.iot
set GOPROXY=https://goproxy.cn,direct
set GOROOT=D:\Program Files\Go
set GOSUMDB=off
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=D:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GOVCS=
set GOVERSION=go1.17.2
set GCCGO=gccgo
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=D:\Program Files\Go\src\go.mod
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -o2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\ChenHN\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build613208781=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches

$ set
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
APPDATA=C:\Users\ChenHN\AppData\Roaming
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME=CHENHN
ComSpec=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
DriverData=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
GOPATH=D:\go3
GOROOT=D:\Program Files\Go
GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=D:\Program Files\Go
HDDL_INSTALL_DIR=C:\Program Files\Common Files\AxxonSoft\DetectorPack\NeuroSDK\hddl\
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\ChenHN
JAVA_HOME=D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22
KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK=TRUE
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\ChenHN\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER=\\CHENHN
MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Phantom\plugins\
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=8
OS=Windows_NT
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\NetSarang\Xftp 6\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetSarang\Xshell 6\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;E:\work\stream_server\ffmpeg-4.2.3-win64-static\bin;D:\Program Files\Graphviz\bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;D:\Program Files\Go\bin;D:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;D:\msys64\mingw64\bin;D:\msys64\usr\bin;C:\Users\ChenHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Users\ChenHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\;C:\Users\ChenHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;C:\Users\ChenHN\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ChenHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;%JRE_HOME%\bin;D:\Program Files\Bandizip\;C:\Users\ChenHN\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22\jre\bin;D:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin;E:\work\stream_server\ffmpeg-4.2.3-win64-static\bin;C:\Users\ChenHN\go\bin;C:\Users\ChenHN\AppData\Roaming\npm
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 13, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=9e0d
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
PROMPT=$P$G
PSModulePath=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
SESSIONNAME=Console
SystemDrive=C:
SystemRoot=C:\WINDOWS
TEMP=C:\Users\ChenHN\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\ChenHN\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN=CHENHN
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=CHENHN
USERNAME=ChenHN
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\ChenHN
WEB_HLS_CONTENT_PATH=C:\ProgramData\AxxonSoft\AxxonNext\HLS\
windir=C:\WINDOWS
WXDRIVE_START_ARGS=--wxdrive-setting=0 --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer --enable-features=NetworkServiceInProcess
```

code gb_test

```
package main
/*
int add(int a,int b){
    return a+b;
}
 */
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(int(C.add(C.int(1),C.int(2))))
}
```

build output error

```
$ D:\go2\src\gb_test>go build -x -o text.exe gb_test
WORK=C:\Users\ChenHN\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build2706563000
mkdir -p $WORK\b041\
cd D:\Program Files\Go\src\runtime\cgo
TERM='dumb' CGO_LDFLAGS='"-g" "-O2"' "D:\\Program Files\\Go\\pkg\\tool\\windows_amd64\\cgo.exe" -objdir "$WORK\\b041\\" -importpath runtime/cgo -import_runtime_cgo=false -import_syscall=false -- -g -O2 -I "$WORK\\b041\\" -g -o2 -Wall -Werror "D:\\Program Files\\Go\\src\\runtime\\cgo\\cgo.go"
# runtime/cgo
cc1.exe: fatal error: opening output file 2: Permission denied
compilation terminated.
```

I tried reinstalling golang,restat computer , close windows defender , add the GOCACHE dir and GOTMPDIR dir to Trust zone , clear GOCACHE dir and GOTMPDIR dir and  GOMODCACHE dir , but it still doesn't work .
when i use admin rights , it still doesn't work .

```
# admin rights
$ D:\go2\src\gb_test>go build -x -o text.exe gb_test
WORK=C:\Users\ChenHN\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build4202487223
mkdir -p $WORK\b001\
cd D:\go2\src\gb_test
TERM='dumb' CGO_LDFLAGS='"-g" "-O2"' "D:\\Program Files\\Go\\pkg\\tool\\windows_amd64\\cgo.exe" -objdir "$WORK\\b001\\" -importpath gb_test -- -g -O2 -I "$WORK\\b001\\" -g -o2 "D:\\go2\\src\\gb_test\\main.go"
# gb_test
cgo: cannot parse gcc output $WORK\b001\\_cgo_.o as ELF, Mach-O, PE, XCOFF object
```

But it only work in goland ide debug model

```
# debug model 
GOROOT=D:\Program Files\Go #gosetup
GOPATH=D:\go3 #gosetup
"D:\Program Files\Go\bin\go.exe" build -o D:\go2\src\gb_test\gb_test.exe -gcflags "all=-N -l" gb_test #gosetup
"D:\Program Files\JetBrains\GoLand 2021.2.3\plugins\go\lib\dlv\windows\dlv.exe" --listen=127.0.0.1:1081 --headless=true --api-version=2 --check-go-version=false --only-same-user=false exec D:\go2\src\gb_test\gb_test.exe -- -a #gosetup
API server listening at: 127.0.0.1:1081
3
```

```
# run model 
GOROOT=D:\Program Files\Go #gosetup
GOPATH=D:\go3 #gosetup
"D:\Program Files\Go\bin\go.exe" build -o D:\go2\src\gb_test\gb_test.exe gb_test #gosetup
# gb_test
cgo: cannot parse gcc output $WORK\b001\\_cgo_.o as ELF, Mach-O, PE, XCOFF object
```

Comment: Try rebooting first, see if that helps. Then include `which go`, `go env`, `env`, `gcc -v` and `which gcc` output, unedited.

Comment: I have tried rebooting many times ,and I add some env ,thanks.I still need some help.